# What is best way to use file_put_contents to write PHP code to file?

Tags: php, file, overwrite, htmlspecialchars

Here is the script:

```
<?php 

$line0PHP = '<?php';
$line1PHP = 'defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );';
$line2PHP = 'jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin');';
$line3PHP = 'jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter');';
$line4PHP = 'class&#32;plgSystem'.$titleString.'plugin&#32;extends&#32;JPlugin';
$line5PHP = '{';
$line6PHP = 'function plgSystem'.$titleString.'plugin()';
$line7PHP = '{';
$line8PHP = '}';      
$line9PHP = '}';
$line10PHP = '?>';

$phpFileOutput = $line0PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line1PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line2PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line3PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line4PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line5PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line6PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line7PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line8PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line9PHP.'&nbsp;'.$line10PHP;

$varOutputPhp = print_r($phpFileOutput, true);

file_put_contents($root,$varOutputPhp);

?>
```

`$root` and `$titleString` are defined earlier.

Comment: Watch out, you have some "smart quotes" in your code. PHP only supports ordinary single and double quotes.

Comment: Consider a [heredoc](http://php.net/heredoc) string and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before writing to the file instead.

Comment: HTML entities are processed by browsers, not PHP. You should write the real characters to the file.

Comment: Just as Barmar said, those smart/curly quotes will immediately throw an error. Change to `$title = 'titleValue';`

Comment: `titleValue` is updated.  I just had that pulled from the word processor.  It was not in the code this way.

Comment: What problem do you have if you write ordinary characters instead of HTML entities? There's no reason it shouldn't create the file that way. `file_put_contents` doesn't care what you're writing.

Comment: @Barmar I tried the full php text but the file did not load the script.  There was just an empty directory.

Comment: Show the code you tried to write, there must be an error in it.

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the code to reflect the exact script details.

Comment: Why do you use print_r? Don't see any sense in it. What is the return value of file_put_contents? If it is false, than no file was written. Maybe you do not have the rights to write a file there or the directory does not exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quoting problems, because you have single quotes inside your single-quoted strings. You need to either escape them, or use double quotes. And you still have a number of HTML entities that need to be replaced with normal characters.

```
<?php 

$line0PHP = '<?php';
$line1PHP = "defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );";
$line2PHP = "jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin');";
$line3PHP = "jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter');";
$line4PHP = 'class plgSystem'.$titleString.'plugin extends JPlugin';
$line5PHP = '{';
$line6PHP = 'function plgSystem'.$titleString.'plugin()';
$line7PHP = '{';
$line8PHP = '}';      
$line9PHP = '}';
$line10PHP = '?>';
$phpFileOutput = $line0PHP.' '.$line1PHP.' '.$line2PHP.' '.$line3PHP.' '.$line4PHP.' '.$line5PHP.' '.$line6PHP.' '.$line7PHP.' '.$line8PHP.' '.$line9PHP.' '.$line10PHP;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $text = "<?php \n";
    $text .= "defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );\n";
    $text .= "jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin');\n";
    $text .= "jimport( 'joomla.html.parameter');\n";
    $text .= "class plgSystem".$titleStringplugin." extends JPlugin\n";
    $text .= "{\n";
    $text .= "function plgSystem".$titleString."plugin()\n";
    $text .= "{\n";
    $text .= "}\n";
    $text .= "}\n";
    $text .= "?>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct way of writing the code :
    file_put_contents($filename, $newfilecode);

Comment: How does that help? It's just different variable names.